# Contract creation - "previous existence" of the contract

Tags: contract-deployment, yellow-paper

I am reading the [ethereum yellow paper](http://yellowpaper.io/), chapter 7, on contract creation.
There it mentions how the address `a` of the created contract is derived and then describes the state after the creation. Namely, it says that the newly created contract's balance is `v+v'` (where v is the endowment and v' is

> the acount's pre-existing value, in the event it was previously in
>   existence

)

I wonder, in what case is it possible that account existed before its creation? (Or did I get something completely wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reading the paper correctly, and indeed it is bemusing. My understanding was that a contract address can never be duplicated given how it is defined:

> "The address of the new account is defined as being the rightmost 160
>   bits of the Keccak hash of the RLP encoding of the structure
>   containing only the sender and the nonce."

I suspect it is stated like that for completeness. Consider for example that in your Genesis file (on a private chain) you specify that a particular contract address has an initial endowment of Ether..

Because contract addresses are **not** random you could pre-emptively discern what a contract address will be and give it a pre-existing value.

Comment: I suppose it's also covering the (extremely unlikely) case of a hash collision with an account with a private key.